# Controlling a Link Sprite camera through an AVR - how to get the data to a PC?

Tags: usb, avr, uart

I have a Link Sprite camera through which I intend to take image captures and store them into an EEPROM. Later, I want to extract the data from the EEPROM and display the image on a PC. What are my options here?

I imagine UART is required to transmit the data to the PC, but what measures need to be taken on a PC to correctly extract this information? Are there any programs that allow you to send and save arbitrary bytes of data sent over USB?

I have purchased a UART to USB serial converter for this purpose, but am a but lost on where to begin with the associated computer program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes for this sort of thing some of the older file transfer protocols such as [XMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmodem) are worth a look. While the speed and error correction aren't as good as many other protocols an advantage is that it's a simple protocol that has a small memory footprint. A search for "AVR xmodem source code" yields quite a few results, for example:

[Procyon AVRlib: xmodem.c Source File](http://www.procyonengineering.com/embedded/avr/avrlib/docs/html/xmodem_8c-source.html)

On the PC side you can run a terminal emulator program and you'll find many that support XMODEM. [Tera Term](http://ttssh2.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en) is one example of a free one that supports it. You'll just need to open the COM port that's been assigned to your USB converter and do a File | Transfer | XMODEM | Receive once your AVR has started the transmission.